# Printing the remaining references using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to print the remaining entries in a `.bib` file using `biblatex`, that is, I have a large set of entries which I print at several places throughout a document using various calls to `\printbibliography`, and then I want to end by printing whatever references that have not yet been printed. The desired solution should not depend on the `.bib` entries themselves, that is, the whole point is not to have to go through the entries and add keywords or similar.

My current non-working solution uses `\AtEveryBibitem` to put printed entries in a category to be able to print all entries that are not yet in this category. This strategy of course works only halfway, though, since it ends up in an oscillation where the uncategorized entries ends up in the category every second time since `\AtEveryBibItem` is also run for these entries when they are printed (so if the `\AtEveryBibitem` statement can in some way be reset before the last call to `\printbibliography` that would be a solution).

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author    = {Guyon, Isabelle and Elisseeff, Andr\'{e}},
  journal   = {The Journal of Machine Learning Research},
  pages     = {1157--1182},
  title     = {{An introduction to variable and feature selection}},
  volume    = {3},
  year      = {2003}
}
@book{ref2,
  author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  year      = {1993},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
@inproceedings{ref3,
  author    = {Conf Author},
  title     = {Conf Title},
  year      = {2040},
  keywords  = {confpaper}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{printed}
\AtEveryBibitem{\addtocategory{printed}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % The .bib file contains several hundreds of entries

\printbibliography[title={Journal articles},type=article]
\printbibliography[title={Conference papers},keyword=confpaper]
% Many other bibliographies are printed using various \printbibliography statements

% And now the entries that have never been printed should be printed
\printbibliography[title={Uncategorized},notcategory=printed]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\AtEveryBibitem` does not work since in `biblatex` the `\bibitem`s are loaded at the beginning of a document and not when a list of references is printed (e.g., `\printbibliography`).  An alternative is to add a hook to the instruction for printing the records. An option is to insert the information about the category in the `finentry` bib macro that is called at the end of the instructions to display a bib record. In addition we can add toggle to turn off the feature when we print the other bib records.

```
\newtoggle{categorise} % load the etoolbox package, \usepackage{etoolbox} 

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{printed}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{categorise}
    {\addtocategory{printed}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    {}
    }%
    \finentry
  }
```

then

```
\nocite{*} % The .bib file contains several hundreds of entries

\toggletrue{categorise}
\printbibliography[title={Journal articles},type=article]
\printbibliography[title={Conference papers},keyword=confpaper]
% Many other bibliographies are printed using various \printbibliography statements


% And now the entries that have never been printed should be printed
\togglefalse{categorise}
\printbibliography[title={Uncategorized},notcategory=printed]
```

With the MWE this yields

[image]

Comment: Not the desired answer... The desired solution should simply print whatever has not yet been printed. The `\printbibliography` statement examples were simply examples, so a solution should not depend on certain types or keywords (I modified the second `\printbibliography`-statement and added a keyword to one of the entries to exemplify).

Comment: You can modify the filter by adding the negation of the conditions in the various `\printbibliography`s.

Comment: Works perfect apart from one thing: adding more references under each heading makes a dot and a space, ". ", appear before the label, that is, adding a second conference paper turns the output label into ". [2]". The problem seems to be that the parentheses in the `\iftoggle`-statement are mismatched so that `\finentry` is only run for the `\togglefalse` case.